# robot rotates instead of going to the goal (dwa_local_planner)

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see the following two videos about the behaviour of the robot ([video1](https://youtu.be/2_va6733bbU), [video2](https://youtu.be/_u4eBcbD2xM)).  The robot sometimes moves pretty well, but sometimes just keep spinning around.  Such behaviour really confuses me, and your help to solve it is greatly appreciated.

I use ROS navigation stack with dwa_local_planner.  I have two computers: one on the robot the publish odometry and laser scan, and the other desktop running the navigation stack.  Both computers are on a local network, and I use chrony to sync their time.  However, my hunch is that the negative delay shown in tf_monitor (see videos above) might be the cause of it, but I'm not totally sure.  Also, if you find other things in the video don't seem right, please let me know too.

Here is the setting of dwa_local_planner.

```
  DWAPlannerROS:
  # Robot configuration parameters  
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 0
  acc_lim_th: 3.2

  max_vel_x: 0.5
  min_vel_x: 0.0
  max_vel_y: 0
  min_vel_y: 0

  max_trans_vel: 0.5
  min_trans_vel: 0.1
  max_rot_vel: 1.0
  min_rot_vel: 0.2

  # Goal Tolerance Parameters
  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.2
  latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false

  # Forward Simulation Parameters
  vy_samples: 0

  # Trajectory scoring parameters
  occdist_scale: 5
```

Here is the tf_tree

[image: image description]

Thanks for your help in advance!

**[EDIT]**

One way that seems to bypass the problem for me is to increase acc_lim_x, acc_lim_th, and acc_lim_trans to really really high, even higher than the true limit of my robot (see [video 6](https://youtu.be/_eE0fYeAD1E)).  All previous videos showed that, when the robot exists the rotating behavior, all candidate trajectories were somehow pretty short, which means that the velocity is very small.  To force dwa_local_planner considering a wider range of velocity (hence wider range of candidate trajectories), one way is to increase acc_lim, because candidate velocities are determined by vel +/- acc_lim.  While increasing acc_lim bypass this particular issue, it is still unclear to me why the dwa local planner, when the robot rotates, keeps choosing those trajectories of small velocities and therefore prevents speeding up toward the target.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210453/robot-rotates-instead-of-going-to-the-goal-(dwa_local_planner)/) by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-06-03**:
p.s. Once I increase the publishing rate of /odom to 100Hz, the delay of tf frames improved.  However, the rotating behavior persists (see [video](http://youtu.be/XwYP84mikCk)).  I also plotted the /cmd_vel, looks like it is the planner that wants to rotate the robot, instead of motor's problem.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-04**:
What version of ROS is this?

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-06-04**:
it's Indigo

**Comment by [942951641@qq.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/38911/942951641@qq.com/) on 2020-04-21**:
who can recommend a param setting about costmap and dwa params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As an experiment, can you set forward_point_distance to 0?

**Edit:** What if you set path_distance_bias to 0?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-06-04**:
Thanks for your suggestion.  I've tried that, but it did not eliminate the spinning and the robot still behaves similarly.

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-06-05**:
Please see [video 4](https://youtu.be/qpYewsP1of4).  I've set forward_point_distance and path_distance_bias to 0, and plot cost cloud.  I also suspect whether the acceleration limitation, sim_time,  and vx_samples limited dwa planner, so I increased their values.  However, the robot still spins.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-09**:
Do you see the same behavior with a lower max_rot_vel?

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-06-18**:
See [video 5](http://youtu.be/bj3qqxwDyiY). I lowered the max_rot_vel from 1 to 0.5. It seems to help a little bit, but it still rotates sometimes.  I noticed that the robot always moves smoothly for one direction, but not the other way around.  Could it be related to orientation of, say, maps?

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-08-03**:
Hi there, my robot seems to exhibit similar behaviour, did you find a solution?

**Comment by [PT](https://answers.ros.org/users/21259/pt/) on 2015-08-03**:
I didn't find the 'true' solution, but see [EDIT] to see the way I bypass the issue.

**Comment by [al_ca](https://answers.ros.org/users/55624/al_ca/) on 2020-11-19**:
Hello there, did you solved your problem?